# Java Applet allowed for Javac or other jar access?

Tags: java, javafx, compiler-construction, applet, client

I am involved in a project that will need to run via web and have access to java's compiler tools and/or javacc api.  My team is thinking of using a java applet to make it web based.  I'm wondering if there are certain limitations on what an applet can and cannot do in this case.  I would assume that since access to the compiler would be done on the server, not the client's machine, that this wouldn't be a problem.  Does an applet allow us to separate the two as described?

Comment: The applet would be running within the context of the clients machine, so unless you have some kind of means for the applet to talk back to the server, the applet is going to want to use the clients java compiler. This raises to issues. The applet runs in a sand box, limiting what an applet can do. Access to the local file system is defiantly high on the restriction list and I'm pretty sure so are socket connections. If you can control the client security policy file, then this is less likly to be an issue

Comment: This is what I was really getting at.  JavaFX with it's tag or the <applet> tag it's still going to need to access the compiler.  So you say that the applet will want to use the client's compiler.  We certainly want to avoid access to the client's security policy.  So what is decided to be run on the client's machine and what's decided to run on the server?  Or does an applet/ javafx both try to run on the client machine?  We certainly need access to a compiler, as well as access to a database for user info.  Surely there's a way for user info, but access to a compiler seems tricky.

Comment: Both will want to run on the client machine. If you want a thick client (using either Swing or JavaFX), they need to run on the client. While its possible to use things like RMI or SOAP/JSON to access data on the server, the client will still need permission to access it. Generally web deployed apps have tighter security restrictions (which is only fair), but you can do things to relieve it, like signing applets for example

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer, this has been helpful.  I understand that it would want to run in a sandbox, but why limit access to a server?  If it's in a sandbox on the client machine, then what would be the worry of sending and receiving from a server (in this case compile a source file that the user submits).  This happens all the time with http (port 80 -- why not use it for this?).  So a signed applet will alleviate this issue?  I need to make my proposal for this technology very soon.  Perhaps there is a better way of doing this that you, or someone, knows of?

Comment: You'd have to try, but I think a socket to a web serve might be achievable. There any many reasons why an applet might be restricted this way, to prevent the applet from downloading malicious code from a third part source for example.with the power of a URLClassloader, applets can (with the right scrutiny permissions) load classes from a server. You might like to also consider the use of [JNLP](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-142562.html) over applets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An applet (and even a JavaFX applet) can work in this situation if the applet is [signed](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm#BABJGFBH).  There are numerous subtle pitfalls with applets, so I would advise prototyping before committing to that technology.  Follow the [JavaFX deployment guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm) to see how to deploy a JavaFX based applet.

I had thought that to compile Java, you needed to have the full Java Development Kit installed (which would be tricky to ensure in an applet deployment situation).  But it seems that the compile API is included in the [javax.tools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html) API included with the standard Java Runtime Environment.  So this likely means that you could develop your solution, including client based deployment and compilation of Java code, without requiring the user install the full Java Development Kit.

You may alternately wish to consider a client/server solution where the compilation can be performed on the server.  An example of such an approach (with a Java WebStart based solution) is the [TopCoder Algorithm Competition Application](http://apps.topcoder.com/wiki/display/tc/The+Algorithm+Competition+Arena).  Here is a jnlp file (http://apps.topcoder.com/wiki/display/tc/The+Algorithm+Competition+Arena) to run this application.  I suggest you register an ID at TopCoder using the application and try out writing and compiling some code using it.  The TopCoder implementation uses plain Swing as it was written before JavaFX existed, but you could equally use JavaFX for your implementation if you preferred.

If you additionally need an editor (with syntax aware text styling) for the code you will be compiling, you could use something like this [CodeMirror](http://jewelsea.wordpress.com/2011/12/11/codemirror-based-code-editor-for-javafx/) based editor embedded in JavaFX.  The CodeMirror based solution wraps the editor in html based `WebView` control.  For JavaFX 8 you will probably be able to make use of the new `TextFlow` control for a [syntax highlighting text editor](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2013/02/14/experimenting-with-textflow-from-javafx8/), but that API is not part of a supported public release yet.

---

**Update**

I got this work using the strategy outlined in this answer.

[image: javaappletusingjavac]

The image is an html page allowing access as an applet or a webstart application to the client code editor.  The top area of the image is the code editing area which is based on a WebEngine with an embedded syntax highlighting CodeMirror JavaScript editor that supports Java editing.  The bottom area of the image is the output of compiling the code in the editor locally on the client machine and subsequently running it.  The output constists of any compilation errors, any program output to sysout, as well as any runtime exceptions printed to syserr.  The tricky parts of the solution were:

1. Working out how to capture sysout and syserr and redirect them to a JavaFX control.
2. Finding the Java compiler.

The default Oracle Java Runtime Environment Provider merely provides a generic interface to a Java Compiler implementation, but it provides no java compiler implementation itself - that implementation is only included in the tools.jar included with the jdk.  So when I packaged my applet, I included the tools.jar in the packaging for the applet.  I had some difficulty getting the service provider interface to get me an instance of the javac compiler, so in the end, I just instantiated it using the following line:

```
JavaCompiler compiler = new com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool();
```

The above is somewhat brittle as sun may change their private com.sun classes at any time - but at least it worked in this instance.

Another thing to be aware of is that if you ship a tools.jar with a javac compiler which is earlier than the runtime environment that you have available for your system, then you might get some warnings such as below:

```
warning: C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/Object.class): major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
  It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
```

The above warning occurred because I shipped the applet with a java 7 tools.jar and ran the applet with a java 8 runtime (note that the applet worked fine regardless of those warnings).

**Update**

I put the code for this solution in a [github repository (project name conception)](https://github.com/jewelsea/conception).  The updated solution uses the [Eclipse Compiler for Java](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/index.php) rather than the Oracle Java Compiler.  Mostly because, for the Eclipse Compiler, it is a separate jar (only 1.8meg rather than the 14meg tool jar of the oracle distribution) and the licensing is a bit clearer.  Because the Java compiler interface is pluggable, the Oracle compiler can still be used if tools.jar is placed on the classpath.

Comment: Thanks jewelsea, this has helped a lot and is exactly what we're looking for.  I am developing the ui in JavaFX Scene Builder, which uses an fxml file.   I looked into your suggestion for using an applet/webstart.  I think we want to go with the applet, since there is a requirement that it runs inside a browser.  I get a little lost with what I have to do next-- the html code that would contain the .fxml file.  I was wondering if you wouldn't mind posting some of your solution so I can see the whole structure, from the .java file to the .html file?

Comment: OK, I'll post it as GitHub project some time in the next couple of days.

Comment: I updated the post to link to the [GitHub project](https://github.com/jewelsea/conception) for this.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah applets can access them and can be a good choice. But it has very limited/ dull look and feell. Go for JavaFx in this you can define your own StyleSheet so it will give you a very good look and feel and yeah definitely it will separate the two layers too.

[JavaFx Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/)

Comment: It looks like that would be great for what I'm doing.  There's a lot of drag and drop functionality in the UI we're designing.  So I assume that JavaFX can be web-based too?

Comment: Yes it is.. You can run JavaFX on web browsers too http://mkblog.exadel.com/2009/01/running-javafx-applications-in-a-browser/  
And with JavaFX you can have drag and drop functionalities as well..

Comment: Also Read this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html

Comment: Very thankful for your help!  I'm not sure I would have looked in this direction if you hadn't mentioned it.  I'm going to propose we use this.  The only thing I haven't really found solid info on is how it works to be web based; within an applet, or it's own thing, or what.

Comment: JavaFX is used to create standalone application plus it can be integrated on web pages. You need to create the application and build a jar file then you can use this jar file on your webpage. It is its own thing, just like applet, you can create desktop application and using HTML tag `<applet>` you can deploy on web. Same way, you need to create desktop application using JavaFX and then you need to embed it on your web http://mkblog.exadel.com/2009/01/running-javafx-applications-in-a-browser/ (same link mentioned above)

Comment: The links to the exadel blog are outdated and refer to the obsolete JavaFX 1.x technology.  Instead see the [JavaFX 2.0 deployment guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm) for information about deploying JavaFX as an applet.